# Can't get the configuration file from Google when integrating google sign-in into Android Application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am following the following article:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

They have an option there to "Get Configuration File" by just entering your cloud-platform app name and your android app's package.  However, when I do this, I get text-box saying:

> "To use Google Sign-In, you'll need to provide the SHA1 of your
>   signing certificate so we can create an OAuth2 client and API key for
>   your app."

The button to "Enable Google-Sign In" is disabled, and there's no place to enter a SHA1 key manually....I had done this previously, and if i remember, this page would automatically find by SHA1 key once I entered the necessary info.

I have double checked that my cloud platform application has a client-id for android application defined and I double-checked the package names as well.

Comment: UPDATE: Ironically, I was able to Enable sign-in by going through the same process on Windows 10 Edge browswer. Not sure if problem was on my end or google's, but working now.

Answer (score 1):

Go into [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and agree to new Terms of Service. It'll will work after that